# Borders doubling up on Jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports

I may be approaching this the wrong way but I've created a few Jasper reports now (Eclipse plugin) which I am exporting variously to pdf, docx and odt.  The only way I've found to create 'tables' is to position adjacent text boxes. I've noticed that I get lines of double thickness if I leave borders overlapping (i.e upper box has a solid bottom border and lower box has a solid upper border), even if I position them on top of each other.

So far no problem as I have been configuring the borders to not overlap (i.e. where 2 text boxes overlap I leave one of the borders as transparent).  However one of my sub reports is just a repeating box in the detail section though so I can't do this here or the bottom or top would be missing. I'm assuming this must come up a lot ?  Is there a way around this ?

I must admit I haven't tried setting the bottom border blank yet and adding a line at the bottom of the 'table' as I'm hoping there may be a more appropriate technique ?

Apologies if this isn't clear.  Please let me know if not.

Thanks,

Comment: mind if you can make us little peek in your expected and actual display, for better understanding.

Comment: I've actually fixed it with the line approach as I'm under a bit of time pressure. I'll leave the question open and add an image later if that's okay as I'm sure there must be a better way.  Thanks for answering, it is a difficult thing to describe.